# MongoNetworkError: connection 3 to cluster0-shard-00-02-z0urk.mongodb.net:27017 closed

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, server

> { MongoNetworkError: connection 3 to
>   cluster0-shard-00-02-z0urk.mongodb.net:27017 closed
>       at TLSSocket. (/home/fahad/Personal Work/Nodejs/Node js start/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:352:9)
>       at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:276:13)
>       at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:13)
>       at _handle.close (net.js:610:12)
>       at TCP.done (_tls_wrap.js:386:7)   name: 'MongoNetworkError',   errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
>   [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }

```
module.exports = (app, express , mongoose, path, bodyParser) => {

    app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "../../dist")));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());


    mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://fahad:123@cluster0-z0urk.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true', {useNewUrlParser: true})
    .then(()=>console.log("DB server connect"))
    .catch(e => console.log("DB error", e));
};
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had same problem when i want to connect to https://cloud.mongodb.com "mongoDB Atlas"
This problem happened to me because when I built project, my IP in this time store in security -> IP Whitelist.

You will only be able to connect to your cluster from the following list of IP Addresses in IP Whitelist.

I manage to solve this problem by using IP 0.0.0.0/0 this help me to connect from anywhere.

Would that help you?

Comment: This one also helped me, by just resetting the option to the current ip adress.

Comment: I have allowed access from anywhere i.e. IP whitelisting has 0.0.0.0/0, still getting this error that too randomly. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

from mongo-db

go to cluster

find security

check the IP, list

add the current ip or the global ip or both
you can add any other ip for development

check step by step in the link below

good luck

https://intercom.help/mongodb-compass/en/articles/1898157-connection-3-to-cluster0-shard-00-00-a1b2c-mongodb-net-27017-closed